# Grabbing unique field from different checkboxes with same class on jQuery .change

Tags: javascript, jquery

for efficiency, I am trying to fashion a jQuery function that's usable by different checkboxes sharing a common class.  The function is triggered by the `.change` event when a user changes one of the checkboxes.  The trick is, I need to capture the unique data of the checkbox changed.

My HTML:

```
Field 123: <input type="checkbox" name="pubfield" value="123" class="pubfield"><br>

Field 999: <input type="checkbox" name="pubfield" value="999" class="pubfield"><br>
```

My jQuery function:

```
$(function(){
    $( ".pubfield" ).change(function() {
        var change_field    = $('.pubfield').val();
        var showit          = $('input.pubfield').prop('checked'); /* true or false */
        alert('Updating field ' + change_field + ' to '  + showit);
    }); 
});
```

Predictably, the function only captures the input value and checkbox state of the first checkbox field, even when the second is changed.  How can I re-use the same function yet capture the unique data from only the checkbox being changed?

Comment: `$(this).val();` is it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function(){
   $( ".pubfield" ).change(function() {
       var change_field    = $(this).val();
       var showit          = $(this).prop('checked'); /* true or false */
       alert('Updating field ' + change_field + ' to '  + showit);
   }); 
});
```

the element `$(this)` represents the element that trigger the event...

Comment: Beautiful!  And got the answer in eight minutes.  Thanks Diego!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `this` in your event handler instead of calling the selector again :

```
$(function(){
    $( ".pubfield" ).change(function() {
        var change_field    = $(this).val();
        var showit          = $(this).prop('checked'); /* true or false */
        alert('Updating field ' + change_field + ' to '  + showit);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I don't think so, is just that is the right answer. :)

Comment: @UmerHayyat well the answers are identical but I've written it from OP snippet by my own, DIEGO CARRASCAL was just faster

Comment: Maybe I asked a very obvious question.  I did try to run down the answer, but the answers I found seemed to involve all the inputs into a single array.

Comment: Don't worry, questioning is how we all learn and I said that it's the right answer not because it's simple, just because that's how jQuery doit... also documentation and examples are sometimes very confusing.